# Установка библиотек рядом с экзэшником

Tags: qt, qt5, cmake

Встала такая проблема: средствами cmake установить скомпилированный экзэшник в некую директорию, вместе со всеми зависимыми библиотеками (qt), чтобы потом эту папку можно было бы просто перенести на другой комп, с такой же архитектурой (и установленными пакетами, вроде built-essential). Причем сделать это на двух системах: linux & windows. И тут встает две проблемы:

1) какие зависимости у Qt библиотек и как их выявить с помощью cmake (если это возможно)

2) при использовании

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::packet> DESTINATION bin)
```

на линуксе будут скопированы библиотеки вида: `libQt5packet.so.5.11.1` а при попытке запуска программа сразу заявит, что не может найти соответствующие библиотеки. А команда

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/install path/bin
```

Никакого результата не дает.

UPD Вторую проблему решил: проблема была в том, что программа пытается слинковаться с алиасом (указателем на библиотеку), который имеет вид `libQt5some_package.so.5`, поэтому его тоже нужно скопировать, для чего в `cmake` есть соответствующий `generator expression`:

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:Qt5::Widgets>)
```

Таким образом под линуксом все (на отдельной машине еще не проверял) вроде работает, но первый вопрос все еще открыт.

Comment: А что делает `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/../bin` по-вашему?

Comment: @arrowd по-моему она добавляет путь по которому приложения ищут библиотеки, но я не уверен.

Comment: Да, и этот путь - `/bin`. Вряд ли ваши библиотеки лежат там.

Comment: @arrowd вы не поняли, виноват, неясно выразился: я имел ввиду, что это путь к той папке bin в каторую все установили

Comment: А может стоит воспользоваться `windeployqt` и соответствующей утилитой под Linux?